TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'insertBefore')
I have a deployed server-side Blazor application in production that has served many Droid Chrome clients for the past few years.  Everything appears to work fine, and I have my own Droid phone that I regularly test with to verify that it works.
However, certain clients will connect and generate the following error that gets emitted to my logs:
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'insertBefore'))
 ---> System.InvalidOperationException: TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'insertBefore')
   at async Task Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.InvokeRenderCompletedCallsAfterUpdateDisplayTask(Task updateDisplayTask, int[] updatedComponents)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

The exception results in a broken circuit and renders the application useless to this user.
As it seems to work for most clients generally, I am rather perplexed on how to proceed to diagnose and troubleshoot this issue.
I did see this error reported on StackOverflow, but the errors seem to be consistently reproduced during development.  That is not this scenario.  Here, this appears to be certain clients encountering this issue, while others have zero problems.

Did you solve it? This looks like a js error. Can you track it? The only occurrence of insertBefore variable is here: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/3307bf66ac87308d157ce9f9fa10bb56c1ebf602/src/Components/Web.JS/src/Rendering/LogicalElements.ts#L289, which is being null probably - for some reason. It can be tracked here: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/3307bf66ac87308d157ce9f9fa10bb56c1ebf602/src/Components/Web.JS/src/Rendering/LogicalElements.ts#L270 where the js creates a comment "marker" and it probably somehow doesn't... Well it is some rendering issue.

Thank you for the insight @Alamakanambra.  The best I can tell this appears to be an extension issue, and it is nearly impossible to debug in a production scenario as it is dependent on the client installation configuration which is readily not available to me.  I found a recent issue on Blazor's GitHub here: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/54842  -- however, it is not 100% certain this is the issue I am experiencing.  I did have reporting customers switch from Chrome to Firefox and the issue did not reproduce there.  So, this appears to be due to local installation (extensions).

I've just face the same issue. When I disabled all the extensions in google chrome the issue is gone. Version 131.0.6778.86 (Official Build) (64-bit)
